# How to make Keras with TF backend use CPU instead of GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I have read some old answers, one offering:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
```

Before importing Keras. It didn't work. I still ask keras to give a list of GPUs and it sees both of them, despite of the command above.

PS: I'm using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Do I have to install TF with cpu version?

Comment: When you install keras `conda install keras` the TensorFlow back-end should have installed. but yes you can try installing TensorFlow separately. For me its always use TensorFlow back end when ever i import keras. I am using python 3.7 and I installed keras using conda. I did not do anything on my windows 10 env

Comment: Me too, it is all going on in a virtual enviroment created by conda. I think this is why the solution given above doesn't work.